# Can a caddy break hard drive?

Tags: hard-disk

Yesterday I bought a new SSD for my old computer and decided to use the HDD as a secondary disk, after formatting the SSD and configuring programs I decided to use the old HDD once again as the primary drive without the SSD, because I couldn't find a caddy that fits my laptop, and it was working correctly. Today I bought a caddy and fit my old HDD to it and tried booting my system but the HDD started beeping periodically (with around 2 seconds period) all of a sudden.

I closed the computer and tried to switch back to HDD as the primary drive but I still couldn't boot and the HDD kept beeping. Is it possible that I damaged it while it is in the caddy? Or do you think that I can recover data from beeping HDD?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that caddy will damage the HDD.
I think that you are possibly damaged the HDD because you removed it several times or that you're not handling it with care. If there is a beep, you can search in the manual what are those beeps mean.
I think you can recover data as long as the disk inside is not damaged, but you need to be extra careful handling it.